# Volver a la ventana principal - Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Gente estoy intentando implementar una interfaz que con una sola ventana se pueda alternar entre diferentes funcionalidades. Quiero dividir el codigo en diferentes archivos .py pero nose como volver a la seccion principal desde otra secundaria. Es decir, la idea es volver a la seccion principal con un boton "volver".
Dejo el codigo de un programa sencillo de prueba

Archivo Main

```
import tkinter as tk
import Prueba2 as P2
root = tk.Tk()
root.maxsize(width = 200, height = 200)
root.minsize(width = 200, height = 200)

def ventana2():
    Boton.place_forget()
    P2.ventana2()

Boton = tk.Button(text = "Boton", command = ventana2)
Boton.place(x = 10, y = 10)

root.mainloop()
```

Archivo de la ventana o sección secundaria

```
import tkinter as tk

def ventana2():
    Boton2 = tk.Button(text = "Boton 2")
    Boton2.place(x = 30, y = 30)
    BotonVolver = tk.Button(text = "Volver")
    BotonVolver.place(x = 80, y = 30)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los métodos `place_forget()`, `grid_forget()` y `pack_forget()` simplemente eliminan el widget del administrador de geometría de turno, sin eliminar el widget en si. Para poder volver a mostrar dicho widget es necesario volver a llamar a su método `place`, `grid` o `pack` de nuevo.

El otro gran problema al que te enfrentas es que el botón encargado de ocultar y volver a mostrar la ventana principal creas en la ventana secundaria. Como se ha comentado, debes volver a llamar al método place del widget de la ventana principal para volver a mostrarla, por lo que debes pasar una instancia del mismo a la función que crea la secundaria o bien pasar una función a llamar por el botón "volver".

Creo que una opción bastante simple y que no altera mucho tu planteamiento original sería:

- Implementar todo el contenido e cada ventana en un `Frame`. Esto simplificaría mucho tu problema ya que para ocultar o mostrar la ventana solo  hay que llamar a `place`/`grid`/`pack` y `place_forget()`/`grid_forget()`/`pack_forget()` del `Frame` y con él se mostraran o ocultaran todos sus hijos.
- Las funciones que crean cada ventana se limitaran a crear dicho `Frame` y su contenido y luego lo retornarán.
- Si generas un botón "volver" o "cerrar" en una ventana secundaria, le pasaremos una callback definida en el módulo principal a llamar por dicho botón. Esta callback se encargará de ocultar la ventana y mostrar la que sea necesaria en su lugar.

Es decir, algo así:

**secundaria.py**

```
import functools
import tkinter as tk



def ventana_secundaria(master, callback=None, args=(), kwargs={}):
    if callback is not None:
        callback = functools.partial(callback, *args, **kwargs)

    main_frame = tk.Frame(master)
    boton2 = tk.Button(main_frame, text="Boton 2")
    boton2.place(x=15, y=30)
    boton_volver = tk.Button(main_frame, text="Volver", command=callback)
    boton_volver.place(x=110, y=30)
    return main_frame
```

**main.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
import secundaria


def mostrar_secundaria():
    principal.pack_forget()
    secundaria.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

def mostrar_principal():
    secundaria.pack_forget()
    principal.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)


root = tk.Tk()
root.maxsize(width=200, height=200)
root.minsize(width=200, height=200)
principal = tk.Frame(root)
boton = tk.Button(principal, text="Boton", command=mostrar_secundaria)
boton.place(x=10, y=10)
secundaria = secundaria.ventana_secundaria(root, mostrar_principal)
mostrar_principal()
root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]